# How to get application flow map data via AppDynamics API?

Tags: api, microservices, integration, appdynamics

I want to load "application flow map" data (that can be seen on the web UI dashboard) from AppDynamics APIs. My goal is to upload the data in Neo4j so we can study our microservices architecture using graph algorithms. The AppDynamics Application Model API doesn't seem to provide data up to this level.

I'll build a client later but for now I use curl with requests like:
curl --user MyUserName:MyPassword https://hostname/controller/rest/applications/OurApp/tiers and variations of this according to the documentation

https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO45/Application+Model+API

Only curl requests for now. See point 2.

I expect a JSON output all the tiers of OurApp with interactions between them.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution https://github.com/Appdynamics/flowmap-builder

Seems to be working so far. Doesn't rely (directly) on APIs but it works!